# How to unit test FormView? Never reaches result page

Tags: django, django-testing

Django's FormView returns 302, something that makes it difficult to test:

```
class A(TestCase):

  def test_add_item(self):
    a_valid_value = "aaa"
    a_invalid_value = "ccc"
    successful_text = "gratz"
    failure_text = "fail"

    resp = self.client.post('/add/', {'item': a_valid_value})
    print(resp.content)  # prints b''
    self.assertContains(resp, successful_text, status_code=??)
```

The `status_code` of first response (Redirect) is 302 and `resp.content` is empty. The issue is that I never get the final response in the test file in order to test the contents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation covers this fully; you can use `follow=True` in the `post` call to follow the redirect, and there is an [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) method to test the redirect itself.